# IP address and port of the host where Docker is running on?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox

I am quite new in this Docker thing and I am trying to get Eclipse Hono works with it according the official guide on Hono (https://eclipse.org/hono/getting-started/). I have some difficulties at the part where I must know the IP address and the port of the host on which Docker engine is running. I created a Ubuntu virtual box for the whole things, so does that mean this "host" is the VM ? Any ideas how can I get the exact IP and port ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your host is VM OS. Now Docker Engine doesn't have a port in general. On the host, a default network interface is created when Docker engine is installed, you can find details about it by using command `docker network ls`
Depending upon your --network parameter to Docker daemon, the respective container will use the underlying network. Most likely it will be bridge under default configuration. Use `docker network inspect bridge` to find out the IP details.
If you want to communicate outside of Host (VM in your case), then use Host networking `--net=host` parameter, which will inherit all network config from underlying OS & you can reach out to Docker Container service from outside world via your Virtualbox Bridge Interface.